# Create a dynamic list from a master worksheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling to work out what I need to do next. After spending a long time searching online I have found the following code that nearly does what I want

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Worksheets("Data Input").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
With Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A3:A" & LastRow)
  Intersect(Worksheets("Data Input").Columns("A:A"), Worksheets("Data Input").Range("A1:A" & LastRow).EntireRow).Copy .Range("A1")
  With .Offset
    .Replace "ARL", "=ARL", xlPart
    On Error Resume Next
    .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlConstants).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    .Replace "=ARL", "ARL", xlPart
  End With
End With
End Sub
```

I have a Master sheet (Data Input), and the code above  searches Column A for the Letters "ARL" and places them in column A on the sheet (Sheet7). I cannot seem to work out how to get the code to enter data from multiple columns based on the search from column A.

Once a row has been found with the search "ARL", I want the code to transfer the data on the row from Columns (A,G,H,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W) on "Data Input" into Columns (A-J) on "Sheet7" based on the search criteria. I also want to make sure this is dynamically done whenever the "Data Input" data is updated or changed in any of the columns selected.

Any suggestions on where to look to find the answer to this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Intersect(Worksheets("Data Input").Columns("A:A"), Worksheets("Data Input").Range("A1:A" & LastRow).EntireRow)` is exactly `Worksheets("Data Input").Range("A1:A" & LastRow)`. So, no meaning of intersection. Then `Range.Offset` without any rows/columns parameters means the range itself. Why do you try `.Replace "ARL", "=ARL", xlPart` twice? After removing all rows without formulas in A:A, no meaning to use it again. To copy the above mentioned columns for the last row in A:A, you must build the discontinuous range to be copied...

Comment: Hi FaneDuru, thank you for your reply. I must admit I borrowed the code from online, and tried to tweak it to work for me, hense the problem I got myself into. So if I understand what you are saying I need to delete the following code `Worksheets("Data Input").Range("A1:A" & LastRow)` With the code `.Replace "=ARL", "ARL", xlPart`, I didn't change that as each line is written slightly differently `.Replace "ARL", "=ARL", xlPart`. I wasn't confident enough to know what I could change in these lines. Could you explain what you mean by build a discontinous range?

Comment: I will prepare an answer and post it in some minutes... But, before that, I would like to clarify the next issue: Why `.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlConstants).EntireRow.Delete`? I mean why `.Offset(1)`? This means to translate the analyzed range with a row. Meaning that "A2:A20" will be transformed and processed as "A3:A21". Is this what you want? It is possible, I do not deny, if you want to skip the second row from processing. I want to be sure that this is what you really want...

Comment: Now, I understood the trick with `.Replace "ARL", "=ARL", xlPart`, followed by `.Replace "=ARL", "ARL", xlPart`. Initially, I missed that the second replacement is done vice versa...

Comment: All I really want to do is search Column A on master sheet for specific word, then transfer that rows data with the specific columns mentioned into Sheet7, and to make it dynamic so it will always update if any information is added to the master sheet. I was looking at INDEX/MATCH as a possibility, but couldn't seem to get it to work the way I wanted, as I seemed to have read before that Offset is more volatile than Index/Match.

Comment: Then, try my answer code, please.

Comment: After reading your post, I have three issues. What are the `.Replace...` lines supposed to do? Do you want to delete the rows that have been transfered? Is `ARL` in column `A` the whole word or just part of the string?

Comment: @VBasic2008: I honestly am not sure how the `.Replace...` part of the code works, as I found this whilst searching for a code that would do what I wanted, and this was the only one that seemed to partially work. The ARL in column A is only 3 letters and this column will only have a 3 letter code. I am trying to create a dynamic list on sheet7 from the master sheet "Data Input" using column A as a filter. It cannot be the whole row that is transferred, but specific columns of Data transferred so, for instance Columns A,G,H,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W to be transferred to Columns A - J on Sheet 7.

Comment: Let's say you have changed a value in one of the mentioned columns. Does the code have to create a new list overwriting the old list or just add the possible new row to the end of the list or copy all of the rows to the new sheet (there will be duplicates) or to avoid duplicates, does it have to delete the row that has been transferred or replace `ARL` with something else? And how are the values in each mentioned column changed: manually or by formula?

Comment: If a value is changed, or a line added, or removed on the 'Data Input' page then the information on Sheet 7 needs to be updated. I have uploaded the workbook to easyupload.io/vl186l if you want to take a look at what I am trying to do.

Comment: But you also have to change `Worksheets("Sheet7")` to either `Worksheets("Arsenal Print")` or just `Sheet7`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a terrible `Excel` solution (but some `Excel` wizard might improve on it):

The first four formulas go to cells `A2`, `B2`, `C2`, `D2`:

```
=IF($N2="","",INDEX('Data Input'!A:A,SUM($N$1:$N2)))
=IF($N2="","",INDEX('Data Input'!G:G,SUM($N$1:$N2)))
=IF($N2="","",INDEX('Data Input'!H:H,SUM($N$1:$N2)))
=IF($N2="","",INDEX('Data Input'!Q:Q,SUM($N$1:$N2)))
```

Now cell `D2` is copied until `J2`.

The following two formulas go to `N2` and `O2` (they can be moved afterwards):

```
=IFERROR(MATCH("ARL",INDIRECT(O2,TRUE),0),"")
=ADDRESS(SUM(N$1:N1)+1,1,4,1,"Data Input")&":"&ADDRESS(1048576,1,4,1)
```

Comment: Do these formulas go into the cells of Sheet 7? Or is this a VBA code?

Comment: Into the cells of `Sheet7`. And afterwards copy down.

Comment: @IanMartin: In the workbook you uploaded, when using the formulas, the results in `Arsenal Print` are from rows 3 to 42. You could copy down to row 265.

Comment: Just tried to copy formulas down. Only the first line showed any information, so not quite sure what has happened!

Comment: You let us believe the data in `Arsenal Print` starts in row 2 (`With Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A2:A" & LastRow)`), but it starts in row 3. Write the formulas into a new sheet in the second row and copy them afterwards to the 3rd row in `Arsenal Print` or rewrite them manually.

Comment: Discovered if I copy down Columns N & O then it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code, please. I used column A:A to determine the last row. If you need it to be B:B (like in your original code), please adapt it where `LastRow` takes a value:

```
Sub TESTCopyReplaceDelete()
 Dim LastRow As Long, shD As Worksheet, sh7 As Worksheet

 Set shD = Worksheets("Data Input")
 Set sh7 = Worksheets("Sheet7")
 LastRow = shD.cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row

 With sh7.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    'shD.Range("A2:W" & LastRow).Copy .Range("A1")'copy all the range and delete the useless columns after
    .Range("A1:W" & LastRow - 1).value = shD.Range("A2:W" & LastRow).value
    .Range("B2:F" & LastRow & ",I2:P" & LastRow).EntireColumn.Delete
    .Replace "ARL", "=ARL", xlPart
    On Error Resume Next
     .SpecialCells(xlConstants).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    .Replace "=ARL", "ARL", xlPart
 End With
End Sub
```

***Edited:***

Test the next version, please. It keeps the first 5 rows, even if the values in A1 does not start with "ALR" and it fits the columns width in "Sheet7". I did not understand what exactly "I still have a problem of the page formatting being changed" means. Nothing from the page were the data is copied is changed when the range is copied... If you maybe hoped that the column width will be kept, this does not happen, so the next code fit the columns width:

```
Sub TESTCopyReplaceDeleteBis()
 Dim LastRow As Long, shD As Worksheet, sh7 As Worksheet
 Dim rng As Range, arr As Variant, i As Long

 Set shD = Worksheets("Data Input")
 Set sh7 = Worksheets("Sheet7")
 LastRow = shD.cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
 
 sh7.Range("A1:W" & LastRow).value = shD.Range("A1:W" & LastRow).value
 sh7.Range("B:F,I:P").EntireColumn.Delete
 sh7.Range("A:J").EntireColumn.AutoFit
 
 With sh7.Range("A6:A" & LastRow)
    .Replace "ARL", "=ARL", xlPart
    On Error Resume Next
     .SpecialCells(xlConstants).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    .Replace "=ARL", "ARL", xlPart
 End With
End Sub
```

If you also need some format to be copied, please state it.

Comment: That works, but it has a couple of things that I now need to address. First, for some reason all the columns in Sheet 7 are resized, instead of just transferring the data over. Secondly, on the master sheet Columns G & H have the following formula in them `=IF(ISBLANK(B5),"",D5&", "&C5)` & `=IF(ISBLANK(B5),"",B5)`. To get round the problem of the second formula, I could pull the data from column B, but on Sheet7 the order displayed needs to be A.G,B in the first 3 columns.

Comment: @Ian Martin: You did not say anything about formulas... Do you need the formulas in discussion, or copying the range value will be enough? Wen you say G & H, are you referring to the "Sheet7" sheet, or "Data Input" one? In fact, the formulas can be automatically applied after the columns being processed, but I need to know if what you wrote above is referring to the "Sheet7". Otherwise, please specify what columns must the formula reference. With other words, in which columns of "Sheet7" to be written which formula...

Comment: Copying the range value is sufficient

Comment: @Ian Martin:  If the formula will be more convenient, please specify the columns keeping the formula and formula itself. If value is enough, and no format must be copied, I can use arrays, which will make the code extremely fast, even for big ranges... So, what do you prefer?

Comment: @Ian Martin: Adapted the code to copy values. The arrays variant...

Comment: Columns G & H on the master worksheet "Data Input" have formulas in the cells that provide a result of combining data from columns C & D. Column H has a formula showing the result from Column B. I used to have a formula in the cells of Sheet7 as `=Input Data!A5` and so on across the form. I discovered this isn't dynamic, and I had to go in and manually sort the page out. Which is why I am trying to find a dynamic method that updates itself.

Comment: @Ian Martin: But the former columns C & D do not exist in "Sheet7", anymore... What formula to be written and in which columns? Now, G & H became  B & C... If they used to refer columns which not existing, anymore, the copying value variant should be the best, I think...

Comment: @Ian Martin: Still alive? It is late in my country and I cannot stay too much... So, what did you choose?

Comment: The code added the correct information into cols. A & B, but then cols. D,E,F were missed before the data was added to cols. G, H, & I. I still have a problem of the page formatting being changed when I run the code. Also I think I need to let you know that on the master sheet about 70% of the columns contain formulas in them, so in this instance Columns G,H,R,S,U, & V contain formulas in the master sheet. I don't know if this is also a problem or not, but the Master Sheet "Data Input" has the first 5 rows as headers, whereas "Sheet7" only has the first 2 rows as headers.

Comment: @Ian Martin: I must confess that I do not understand too much... Copying in the last way (without formatting) does not modify any format of "Sheet7". Then, copying the values, the previous formulas do not matter at all. And headers or not headers are treated by the code in the same way, If they have ARL in A:A column, they remain, if not they are deleted...

Comment: I tried the formula again, this time removing the quote mark from the line `shD.Range("A2:W" & LastRow).Copy .Range("A1")` It now puts all the information in the correct columns. It still completely changes the formatting of the size of the columns. I just wish I could show you a screen shot of the before & after! Also all the information in the header in Sheet7 has disappeared which needs to remain. I will be back tomorrow to work out what has to be done to keep the header row untouched and the column widths unchanged when the code is run.

Comment: @Ian Martin: I edited the answer and placed a new version. I explained there what it does. I must leave home for a while, but I can check your feedback on mobile phone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220705/discussion-between-ian-martin-and-faneduru).